# nutch-2.2.1 generator job failed

Tags: nutch

sabayasachi@sabayasachi-Inspiron-3543:~/apache-nutch-2.2.1/runtime/local$ ./bin/crawl urls/ testCrawl false 1
InjectorJob: starting at 2015-07-03 12:42:20
InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: urls
InjectorJob: Using class org.apache.gora.sql.store.SqlStore as the Gora storage class.
InjectorJob: total number of urls rejected by filters: 0
InjectorJob: total number of urls injected after normalization and filtering: 1
Injector: finished at 2015-07-03 12:42:22, elapsed: 00:00:02
Fri Jul 3 12:42:22 IST 2015 : Iteration 1 of 1
Generating batchId
Generating a new fetchlist
GeneratorJob: starting at 2015-07-03 12:42:23
GeneratorJob: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
GeneratorJob: starting
GeneratorJob: filtering: false
GeneratorJob: normalizing: false
GeneratorJob: topN: 50000
GeneratorJob: java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=[testCrawl]generate: 1435907542-1867, jobid=job_local1420236121_0001
    at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:54)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.run(GeneratorJob.java:199)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.generate(GeneratorJob.java:223)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.run(GeneratorJob.java:279)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.main(GeneratorJob.java:287)

---

I am getting this error while executing the crawl command. I am using mysql for storage and nutch version is 2.2.1